# XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG <...definitions

Tags: java, android, android-ksoap2

This is the `WSDL` I created for `php` (Yii) web service call to connect to android. But I get

```
10-19 11:17:36.068: W/System.err(11165): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG <{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}wsdl:definitions name='StatisticController' targetNamespace='http://example.com/webservice/statistic/'>@13:91 in java.io.InputStreamReader@40539de0)
```

XML:

```
<wsdl:definitions name="StatisticController" targetNamespace="http://example.com/webservice/statistic/">
  <wsdl:message name="getGeneralstatRequest"/>
  <wsdl:message name="getGeneralstatResponse">
     <wsdl:part name="return" type="xsd:struct"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="StatisticControllerPortType">
     <wsdl:operation name="getGeneralstat">
       <wsdl:documentation/>
       <wsdl:input message="tns:getGeneralstatRequest"/>
       <wsdl:output message="tns:getGeneralstatResponse"/>
     </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="StatisticControllerBinding" type="tns:StatisticControllerPortType">
     <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
     <wsdl:operation name="getGeneralstat">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://example.com/webservice/statistic/getGeneralstat" style="rpc"/>
        <wsdl:input>
           <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://example.com/webservice/statistic/" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
           <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://example.com/webservice/statistic/" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
        </wsdl:output>
     </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:binding>
   <wsdl:service name="StatisticControllerService">
      <wsdl:port name="StatisticControllerPort" binding="tns:StatisticControllerBinding">
          <soap:address location="http://example.com/webservice/statistic/ws/1"/>
      </wsdl:port>
   </wsdl:service>
```

Webservice is working. I tested with http://www.validwsdl.com/

Java code:

```
    private static String domain_name = URLEncoder.encode("example.com");
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "getGeneralstat";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://"+ domain_name +"/webservice/statistic/";
    //private static final String URL = "http://"+ domain_name +"/webservice/statistic/";
    private static final String URL = "http://"+ domain_name +"/webservice/generalstat2.wsdl";
   private static final String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME;
...
   SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
   SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
   envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
   HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL,8000); // trying 8 sec  
   try {    
     ht.debug = true;
     ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
...
   } catch ...
   } catch ...
   } catch (XmlPullParserException xe) {
   } catch ...
```

I've been trying for 3 weeks, but it's not working. I've read many many topics, but nothing resolved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XMLParserException could get thrown at two points.

1. When the Library tries to generate the SoapObject before the call
2. After the call, when the response object is not a valid XML(for example you could get
   a HTML response with a server error)

Debug your Webservice call and check the dump variables of your HTTPTransportSE Object to find out if your XML is valid. You also can copy paste the content of the dump variables into soapUI to check which of your xml parts are not working.

This helped me alot http://mspmsp.brinkster.net/MobileJava/ch16.htm

I hope it helps.

Comment: You helped me to get through the error. Thank you. Because of the error message I thought it crashes at the first reading and does not correctly understands the WSDL, but as it answered the soapAction and uses the same "definitions" because the webservice it does not undersand ksopa's function call.

Answer (score 0):

Your given wsdl is definitely not correct: There are some namespace-declarations missing plus the
wsdl:definitions tag is not closed properly at the end of the file (maybe a copy+paste error). This is a corrected version:

```
<wsdl:definitions name="StatisticController" 
targetNamespace="http://example.com/webservice/statistic/"
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:tns="http://example.com/webservice/statistic/">
  <wsdl:message name="getGeneralstatRequest"/>
  <wsdl:message name="getGeneralstatResponse">
     <wsdl:part name="return" type="xsd:struct"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="StatisticControllerPortType">
     <wsdl:operation name="getGeneralstat">
       <wsdl:documentation/>
       <wsdl:input message="tns:getGeneralstatRequest"/>
       <wsdl:output message="tns:getGeneralstatResponse"/>
     </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="StatisticControllerBinding" type="tns:StatisticControllerPortType">
     <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
     <wsdl:operation name="getGeneralstat">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://example.com/webservice/statistic/getGeneralstat" style="rpc"/>
        <wsdl:input>
           <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://example.com/webservice/statistic/" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
           <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="http://example.com/webservice/statistic/" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
        </wsdl:output>
     </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:binding>
   <wsdl:service name="StatisticControllerService">
      <wsdl:port name="StatisticControllerPort" binding="tns:StatisticControllerBinding">
          <soap:address location="http://example.com/webservice/statistic/ws/1"/>
      </wsdl:port>
   </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

I recommend importing a WSDL into soapUI as a quick and simple validation step.